# How export postgresql database from Google Clould

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have one project in Google Clould with a Postgres database, someone can help me export this data to my pc?

Answer (score 2):

From the terminal, I had to specify the database IP address, user and password

```
pg_dump -h [IP-ADDRESS] -U [DB-USER] [DB-NAME] > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can ssh to your Google Cloud instance and run the command: **pg_dump db_name > db_name.sql**. The pg_dump command exports the given database to sql format. You can then download the database to your local computer.

See this link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: so why don't you show a REAL example