# Copy data from Postgres DB (GCP Project A) to another Postgres DB (GCP Project B)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I would be happy to get your help / feedback re data load.

Goal:
Load source data from a Postgres database, which is located in GCP project A to another Postgres database, which is located in GCP project B.

Challenge:
Get a connection (I have an IAM account with sufficient rights to run a `COPY TO / COPY FROM` command) to the Postgres DB in GCP Project A and copy the table either to a CSV or create a dump that can be used in order to be inserted to another Postgres DB in GCP Project B.
How do I connect to the database (e.g. if I create a key, where shall I store the json keyfile and would that approach even be feasible?) with this IAM email account?

Other ways I've researched were to use psycopg2 (thus I could use the function `cursor.copy_expert` (which doesn’t need any superuser right or Postgres user credentials and copy the data), but I didn’t succeed in connecting to the database with psycopg2 due to challenges with cloud proxy.

Another idea was to use [pg_dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167498/how-export-postgresql-database-from-google-clould) or [gcloud sql export csv](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/export/csv).
I would be curious if some of you were facing a similar challenge and how did you solve it and what might be the best way/practice

Comment: Do you need to repeat the operation several time? Or to stream the update from A to B? Or it's a one shot copy?

Comment: It should be done daily

Answer (score 2):

Hello after  a lot of searching I've come to these solutions:

If you have continuous copy, you need to use the database migration service, check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/quickstart).

If you have one shot copy:

- you can restore your instance, see the bottom page of this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/restoring?hl=fr)
- you can create a bucket and backup your instance on it, then import it from the other project

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try out [database migration service](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration). You can set up a continuous migration configuration and use Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL.