# Migrate data between PostgreSQL instances on different GCP Projects

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, database-migration

We have two GCP projects - one for UAT environment and one for Prod environment. There are separate PostgreSQL instances in both the projects. How do I migrate relevant data from one SQL instance on GCP QA project to the other instance on GCP UAT project.

Business users would like to add data in UAT environment using an interface, do some testing and move the data to prod environment once it is approved in UAT.

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: Have you've considered to use a one shot copy, as discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72445149/13171940)